# Batch file read INI file from UNC path

Tags: batch-file, ini, unc

So, I've been working on a batch file to collect specific system information, I've run into a road block with opening an INI file that's on the network installation. So obtaining the path is:

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG Query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Zephyr Associates, Inc." /v StyleDir 2^>nul') do set "StyleDir=%%~b"
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Zephyr Associates, Inc." /v StyleDir 2^>nul') do set "StyleDir=%%~b"
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Zephyr Associates, Inc." /v StyleDir 2^>nul') do set "StyleDir=%%~b"
cd %StyleDir%
```

So in this scenario, let's say %StyleDir% is //Server/StyleDir/

Later on in the script we read the Style.ini file with the following:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr SQLiteHome style.ini') do set SQLiteHome=%%a
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr Server style.ini') do set SQL=%%a
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr DataHome style.ini') do set DataHome=%%a
```

At this point I get an error saying we're unable to read the Style.ini. Within the Style.ini I have the following:

```
[Default]
DataHome=C:\ProgramData\Zephyr\Data\
SQLiteHome=C:\ProgramData\Zephyr\Data\
[DataBaseList]
Tons of other lines I don't need to read Right now....
```

Later I populate a txt file that records the information. That script is as follows:

```
::Output
echo StyleDir: %StyleDir% >> SystemInformation.txt
echo SQLiteHome: %SQLiteHome% >> SystemInformation.txt
echo SQL Server: %SQL% >> SystemInformation.txt
echo DataHome: %DataHome% >> SystemInformation.txt
```

So is there a special way that I could get this info recorded from the INI file? I've had thoughts about temporarily mapping a network drive, but the problem with that is knowing what network drives are already mapped so that I don't break what's already there. I'm not even 100% sure that this has to do with the UNC path at all, I just know that when the INI is locally on C:\ that it can be read, but on the network it cannot. Any suggestions for what to try?

Another thing I've noticed is that I can open the Style.ini from a batch file just fine, regardless of the location. I just can't Read it for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, all you have to do is use

```
pushd \\server\dir
```

instead of

```
cd \\server\dir
```

when pointing to the path. Figures it would be something easy. I still get an error, but it'll proceed past it, which is fine by me :-)

Answer (score 0):

You said:

```
I just know that when the INI is locally on C:\ that it can be read, 
but on the network it cannot.
```

That's not true. You can read ini files with UNCs like this:

```
\\ServerName\directory\any.ini
```

The error may be somewhere else, such as unmatched quotes, authentication or missing file. Knowing what the exact error message you get would help debug the precise reason.

**Expanded** in response to complete error msg:

```
CMD does not support UNC paths
```

Implies removing this line

```
cd %StyleDir%
```

in your batch file as you cannot cd unless you map to a drive letter first. Consult map /help for details. Or you can avoid cd'ing to that folder by fixing the findstr command to use the UNC directly, such as:

```
findstr stringToSearch \\full\UNC\path\to\file.ini
```

Which option you choose will depend on what is being done to the found strings. You mention you are populating those strings, but not where. If populating to a file on the remote server, use the drive map option. If populating locally, then use the UNC option.

Comment: \\SERVERNAME\SHARENAME\directory might be \\ALFRED\C$\directory

Comment: @Emacs User
The error is as follows:

    `\\server\folder\Dir\`

    `CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.`

    `FINDSTR: Cannot open style.ini`

    `FINDSTR: Cannot open style.ini`

    `FINDSTR: Cannot open style.ini`

Comment: @Paul so you're saying that because I'm using a UNC path, that this will not work at all? I cannot always use drive letter paths, because it can be different depending on what the original installation person set it up as. Would there be a way around this?